# How to open Outlook's new mail window with prepopulated attachment

Tags: c#-4.0, outlook, office-interop, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I need to open a new email window with a prepopulated attachment when a user clicks some button or link in my application.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Old question, but I also ran in to this so here's a copy and paste solution:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

oMsg.Subject = "subject something";
oMsg.BodyFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
oMsg.HTMLBody = "text body"; //Here comes your body;
oMsg.Attachments.Add("c:/temp/test.txt", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
oMsg.Display(false); //In order to display it in modal inspector change the argument to true
```

You'll need to add a reference to the  `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` component  in your project.

Comment: I think this answer should be marked as the solution.

Answer (score 3):

you can do it using interop services of outlook

```
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

 Outlook.MailItem mail = Application.CreateItem(
        Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem) as Outlook.MailItem;
    mail.Subject = "Quarterly Sales Report FY06 Q4";
    Outlook.AddressEntry currentUser =
        Application.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry;
    if (currentUser.Type == "EX")
    {
        Outlook.ExchangeUser manager =
            currentUser.GetExchangeUser().GetExchangeUserManager();
        // Add recipient using display name, alias, or smtp address
        mail.Recipients.Add(manager.PrimarySmtpAddress);
        mail.Recipients.ResolveAll();
        mail.Attachments.Add(@"c:\sales reports\fy06q4.xlsx",
            Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing);
        mail.Send();
    }
```

Working example can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb644320.aspx)..

Comment: So this look like it uses outlook to actually send the mail in the background. The question is asking how to actually open the new message window with an attachment already attached, leaving me the option to add to the email before sending it.

Comment: Finally someone has the same concern as me. I created the temporary excel from a GridView. I would like to only open a new outlook message with the excel attached and let the user press Send.